# Running a long term session and garbage collection in PHP

Tags: php, session, garbage-collection

What I want is to be able to save a session variable for 12 hours so user don't need to re-log in.

I'm using something like this:

```
if(ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime') !== 3600*12) {
    ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600*12);
}
if(ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime') !== 3600*12) {
    ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600*12);
}

session_start();
```

And I've echoed the vars and they all are set properly. But as long as browser gets closed session gets destroyed and user must log in.

I've read recently (but can't find the resource now) that one should change the location folder for long running session cookies because of garbage collection.

Where/How do I configure that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks ok.
You should check PHPSESSID cookie on the client side first to ensure that it is really set to expire in +12 hours. Since you are saying that "as long as browser gets closed session gets destroyed and user must log in" the cookie is not set to expire in +12 hours. Are you starting the session after you set session.* variables?

Comment: Yes I do use session_start() after that. I've added this to edit.

Comment: What about PHPSESSID cookie in browser?

Comment: What should I verify? Its existance? It exists. I checked with `Chrome developer tools`.

Comment: You should verify cookie expiration time. I think that your session is ok and the only problem is that PHPSESSID cookie is set to expire when the browser is closed.

Comment: In `Chrome` dev tools I can see `Expires: Session` pair. Is that a culprit?

Comment: Looks like it is. Now the question is why does your server ignores "ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 3600*12);". I tried your code in a virtual machine and it worked fine. By the way "ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime') !== 3600*12" will always be true because left part is a string.